# Can I define $f: \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that map $(k,x) \rightarrow kx$ ???

Tags: functions, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p = \{1,2,\ldots, p\}$ with $p$ is a prime number. Can I define a mapping that:

$f: \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that map $(k,x) \rightarrow kx$ ??? that $k\in \mathbb{Z}_p$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $kx \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You can define anything you like, but I'm assuming you want the map to have a certain property?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, yes in my case $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a Galoa finite field with $p$ is a prime number.